Facebook webhook not working. How to fetch leads from facebook webhook?
I want to fetch leads from Facebook using the webhook for page updates and the leadgen subscribe for which i have created the endpoint as Webhook and token and created the post API to fetch leads and store into my database. But Webhooks is not working as soon as new lead is added and i don't the form of data in which it is coming from the webhook?
enter image description hereenter image description hereI have created a webhook end point /webhook and then a API /facebook_leads_webhook to fetch leads from facebook and store it into y database.enter image description hereenter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
